# Diagram with exact sequences

Tags: diagrams, tikz-cd

I have to draw the diagram in the following picture:

[image]

I'm trying to use this code but I cannot draw the vertical part.

```
\begin{tikzcd}  
            0 \arrow[r] 
                & L(-D) \arrow[r] \arrow[d] 
                    & L \arrow[r] \arrow[d]
                        & L/L(-D) \arrow[r] \arrow[d]
                        & 0 \\
            0 \arrow[r]
                & L(-D) \arrow[r] 
                    & L(D) \arrow[r] 
                        & L(D)/L(-D) \arrow[r] 
                            & 0 \\
\end{tikzcd}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please read the documentation of https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz-cd as your image is really basic stuff for `tikz-cd`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
                &                                 & 0                 \arrow{d}                 & 0                 \arrow{d}          &   \\
    0 \arrow{r} & L(-D) \arrow{r}\arrow[equal]{d} & L                 \arrow{r}\arrow{d}        & L/L(-D)           \arrow{r}\arrow{d} & 0 \\
    0 \arrow{r} & L(-D) \arrow{r}                 & L(D)              \arrow{r}\arrow{d}        & L(D)/L(-D)        \arrow{r}\arrow{d} & 0 \\
                &                                 & E(\mathfrak{a})/E \arrow[equal]{r}\arrow{d} & E(\mathfrak{a})/E \arrow{d}          &   \\
                &                                 & 0                                           & 0                                    &
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]