# latex code diagram

Tags: syntax

It will be helpful if someone writes for me the code in latex for the following diagram and explain the code.[image] The inverse limit is taken over s

Comment: Someone did it, not for you but for everybody. See here: http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/generic/diagrams/xypic/doc/xyguide.pdf

Comment: What would be helpful is if you could show us some effort in trying to create this diagram. Searching on the tag [tag:tikz-cd] reveals a lot (for example, [this post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/235942/5764))...

Comment: I would suggest that you start with this question: [Commutative Diagrams](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/115783) and then try to make the diagram yourself using `tikz-cd`. If you have problems, post a minimal document showing what you have tried and then we can help you when you get stuck.

Answer (score 6):

This is a code that demonstrates two solutions: the `psmatrix` environment from `pst-node` (based on `pstricks`) and the `tikz-cd` environment from the homonymous package (based on `tikz-pgf`):

```
\documentclass[pdf]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} 
 \usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{tikz-cd} 

\begin{document}
\texttt{psmatrix solution: }
 \[ \psset{arrows=->, arrowinset=0.25, linewidth=0.6pt, nodesep=3pt, rowsep=0.6cm, colsep = 1cm}
 \everypsbox{\scriptstyle}
 \begin{psmatrix}
%%% nodes
  0 & \varprojlim_{s} M/p^s & \varprojlim_{s} N/p^s & \varprojlim_{s} P/p^s& 0\\%
0 & M & N & P& 0
 %%% horizontal arrows
\ncline{1,1}{1,2} \ncline{1,2}{1,3} \ncline{1,3}{1,4} \ncline{1,4}{1,5}
 \ncline{2,1}{2,2} \ncline{2,2}{2,3} \ncline{2,3}{2,4} \ncline{2,4}{2,5}
 %%% vertical arrows
\psset{nodesepA = -5pt}
 \ncline{1,2}{2,2} \ncline{1,3}{2,3} \ncline{1,4}{2,4}
% \ncline[offset=0.8pt]{2,2}{3,2} \ncline[offset=-0.6pt]{2,3}{3,3}   \ncline[offset=0.6pt]{2,4}{3,4}
 \end{psmatrix}
 \]
\vskip 1cm

\texttt{tikz-cd solution: }
\[ \begin{tikzcd}\everymath{\displaystyle}
  0 \arrow{r}& \smash{\varprojlim\limits_{s}} M/p^s \arrow{r}\arrow{d}& \smash{\varprojlim\limits_{s} }N/p^s \arrow{r}\arrow{d} & \smash{\varprojlim\limits_{s}} P/p^s\arrow{r}\arrow{d}& 0\\%
0 \arrow{r}& M \arrow{r}& N\arrow{r} & P\arrow{r}& 0
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why the useless `\everymath{\displaystyle}`? I'd define `\newcommand{\dvarprojlim}[1]{\mathop{\mathstrut\varprojlim\limits_{#1}}}` so the spacing after `\dvarprojlim{s}` would be good.

Comment: @egreg; it's a residue of an attempt to avoid writing `\limits` repeatedly. I don't know why ythis happens (only in `tikzcd`). Thank you for the suggestion, I'll add it.